# Regex - How can I extract a term between 2 known words in Splunk

Tags: regex, splunk

I have a field called "M" and some of the values are as follows:

"Panorama push to device:013101010578 for device-group: Durham_IPV6_INET_SVCS succeeded. JobId=2480530"

"Panorama push to device:007257000068919 for device-group: Azure-China-Internet-North succeeded. JobId=2480524"

"Panorama push to device:016401009013 for device-group: Austin_Experience_Lounge succeeded. JobId=2480530"

How can I extract just the first string in between each "....device-group: *** succeeded. ....", where *** represents the respective value to be extracted. In the case of the above 3 examples, the 3 values extracted are "Durham_IPV6_INET_SVCS", "Azure-China-Internet-North" and "Austin_Experience_Lounge" respectively.

I tried using the following Splunk command but got no success  :face_with_rolling_eyes::

```
|rex "body\s(?<portNumber>\d+)\s"
```

I appreciate any help on this regex issue.
Thanks,

Comment: Why do you use `body\s(?<portNumber>\d+)\s`? You are not trying to extract a port number, are you? Try `device-group:\s*(?<deviceGroup>\S+)\s+succeeded`

Comment: `(?<=device-group: )[\w-]+` using [positive lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973495/8355969)

Comment: This worked perfectly.
By the way, if I had logs as such:

"Client authentication successful PAN-OS ver: 9.1.11-h3 Panorama ver:10.1.6-h3 Client IP: 10.68.196.211 Server IP: 10.58.217.123 Client CN: 013101004861"
"Client authentication successful PAN-OS ver: 9.1.11 Panorama ver:10.1.6-h6 Client IP: 10.58.90.53 Server IP: 10.58.90.200 Client CN: 010401005346",
How can I extract BOTH the PAN-OS and Panorma ver, i.e,e 9.1.11, 10.1.6-h6, 10.1.6-h3, 9.1.11-h3????


I tried the following but it doesn't work  - | rex field=body "[Panorama][PAN-OS]\s*:(?<Software_Version>.+?) Client"

Comment: Try `PAN-OS\s*ver:\s*(?<PanOS_Version>\S+)\s*Panorama ver:\s*(?<Panorama_Version>\S+)`, see https://regex101.com/r/tEXjZ9/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At search time, use the `rex` command to extract the device-group value.

```
| rex field=M "device-group:\s*(?<deviceGroup>.+?) succeeded"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer!
This works almost perfectly BUT it fails to pick up instances where the text in between "....device-group:" and "succeeded ...." is made up by a series of words with spaces.
Examples include:
1) "Panorama push to device:013101009509 for device-group: Austin Cloud DMZ succeeded. JobId=2484595" where the extracted values should be "Austin Cloud DMZ "
2) "Panorama push to device:013101014290 for device-group: Austin Bank Segmentation succeeded. JobId=2482583" where the extracted values should be "Austin Bank Segmentation"


Can you help on extract such case too?

Comment: Try my revised answer.